# Changing static files path to s3 buckt path django

Tags: python, django, amazon-s3, django-staticfiles

Currently I am getting my static files like this:

```
src="{% static 'website/images/home-slider/plantarte-espacio-4.jpg'%}"
```

And my settings.py look like this:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'staticfiles')

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
  os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'website/static'),
)
```

Now wat I want is that instead of grabbing the static files from the static foleder inside my app. It goes to my AWS S3 bucket I created and uploaded all the files to
Instead of this:

```
src="/static/website/images/home-slider/plantarte-espacio-4.jpg"
```

Do this:

```
src="https://plantarte-assets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/website/images/home-slider/plantarte-espacio-4.jpg"
```

If someone could please help me I would really apreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In the simple case, change your

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

to

```
STATIC_URL = 'https://plantarte-assets.s3.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/'
```

and you should be golden.